# root capacity showing full, but cannot find what's taking so much space

Tags: disk, disk-usage, partitioning, drive, storage

**UPDATE 2**
Thank you all for the help.  It turns out to be like what @steeldriver suggested.
Someone rebooted the machine and manually mount my `/dev/sdc1` back to the original path `/mnt/WD`.
What I did was to umount and disconnect the external drive `/dev/sdc`, and `rm` the still remaining `/mnt/WD` on `/dev/sda1`, then `/` turns back normal with `df` and `du`.
Finally, connect and mount back the `/dev/sdc1`.

So, what the file system
I have 2 internal drives and 1 external drive, all in ext4 format.
`/home` is on `sdb1`, `/mnt/WD` is on `sdc1` which is the external drive.

`df` command showing `/dev/sda1` is full, mounted on `/`
But, I `du -h --max-depth=1 -x` shows only 3.3G, my sda1 is supposed to be 44G.

Any ideas what I should be doing next?

```
root@X3650:/# df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              2013436         0    2013436   0% /dev
tmpfs              405068      6636     398432   2% /run
/dev/sda1        45586292  44282388          0 100% /
tmpfs             2025340         0    2025340   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             2025340         0    2025340   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1        88874936  35925504   48391816  43% /home
tmpfs              405068         8     405060   1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdc1      5813235212 196499792 5323694628   4% /mnt/WD
tmpfs              405068         4     405064   1% /run/user/111

root@X3650:/# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1   50G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    1 44.4G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    1    1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    1  5.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1 86.6G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   1 86.6G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0  5.5T  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0  5.5T  0 part /mnt/WD
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

root@X3650:/# du -h --max-depth=1 -x
56K     ./tmp
4.0K    ./lib64
8.0K    ./media
245M    ./lib
36M     ./srv
12M     ./sbin
2.5G    ./usr
4.0K    ./mnt
8.3M    ./etc
4.0K    ./opt
23M     ./root
9.5M    ./bin
16K     ./lost+found
422M    ./var
35M     ./boot
3.3G    .
```

**UPDATE**

```
root@X3650:~# df -i
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev              503358    402    502956    1% /dev
tmpfs             506335    591    505744    1% /run
/dev/sda1        2916352 201888   2714464    7% /
tmpfs             506335      1    506334    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             506335      4    506331    1% /run/lock
tmpfs             506335     15    506320    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1        5677056 103164   5573892    2% /home
tmpfs             506335     14    506321    1% /run/user/111
tmpfs             506335     11    506324    1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdc1      183140352 384429 182755923    1% /mnt/WD
```

Comment: @ubfan1 hey, I thought max-depth means to show the sum of used space of everything inside that folder.  Without --max-depth, i still get "3.3G . " in the very end.

Comment: What is the output of `df -i`?  See if all the Inodes are taken up.

Comment: Sometimes the cause is writing to a mountpoint when there's not actually  a device mounted there - the used space is hidden when the device subsequently gets mounted

Comment: @Terrance df -i seems fine to me, am I reading it correctly? Result is updated in eidt.

Comment: Yep, that is good.  I have seen them all used before causing a drive to read full.  Just always one more thing to cross off the list causing the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @steeldriver Hi, are you suggesting I manually mount /dev/sda1 to / ?

Comment: No - I'm suggesting that you manually *un*mount `/dev/sdc1` and then see if there are still files at `/mnt/WD` (and the same for `/dev/sdb1` and `/home` - although note that you will need to drop to recovery mode in order to unmount `/home`)

Comment: @steeldriver hi, thx, your suggestion turned out to be true.  Edit in the OP.